# Auditing => History table => other places to look at for auditing of what was changed?

Tags: content-editor

After a user noticed us of the disappearance of a field value, I'm trying to audit what happened in more detail.

I see from the backend 'History' table when the item was edited. But are there other details as for what was changed?

It looks as if a 'Deselect All' was clicked by mistake, in a 'Selected' list.
The field is gone from the 'VersionedFields' table, so I don't have an 'Updated' timestamp value.

Comment: Closing question for merge with 
https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/2345/audit-log-for-seeing-who-updated-content-when