# How to fetch historical field value data

Tags: content-management

I would like to see all the content changes that happened for an item over a period of time.

We were unsuccessful in installing the marketplace module for `Audit Trail` in v10.3. Also, it seems it doesn't show the previous content data.

I checked the `History` table but couldn't find anything related to content.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please check the below post-
https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/2345/audit-log-for-seeing-who-updated-content-when